# Debugging Tests - Getting Testem/Qunit from closing test browser window

Tags: testing, ember.js, qunit, acceptance-testing, ember-app-kit

Ok, I'm using [Ember-App-Kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit) which uses [Testem/Qunit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/tasks/options/testem.js#L3), but I can't figure out how to debug tests, especially since either Testem or Qunit close the QUnit tests window so I can't set any breakpoints, and `node debug` with `debugger` doesn't work since it's in browser.

I tried to set the `debug: true` property in `grunt-contrib-testem` but that didn't do anything..

So if anyone can help, that would be awesome. I'm using the default EAK setup without any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a few things:

1. Keep the `grunt server` task running in one window -- this will rebuild your test assets and compile them into the build/test directory.
2. Run Testem in standalone mode -- you'll first have to install testem via npm (`npm install -g testem`) then call `testem` from your app's root directory. Alternatively, you can run `grunt test:server`, which will let you run testem without installing globally.
3. Drop a `debugger` statement in your `test` body. In an open Chrome window running the Testem harness, open your Developer Tools console window.
4. Refresh the Chrome window, and you'll now have breakpoint capabilities in your tests.